# Exporting map to jpg (multiple times with python)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy, symbology, jpg

I set symbology and exported each raster in my mxd (one by one) to jpg file. My script is ok and it works (it is shown at the bottom).

The question is: how can I customly set my legend?

Now I have those standard labels ("High: #max.number" and "Low: #min.number"), see the image link.

Is it possible to use a python script that sets labels different, for example "Max. value: #maximum number" and "Min. value: #minimum number"?

I have 200 images and renaming each legend is time consuming...

image link (example):

[image]

```
MY SCRIPT:
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, "my_first_layer")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    #turn off all layers
    lyr.visible = False
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    #turn one layer on at a time and export ...
    lyr.visible = True<BR>
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, "D:\\Users\\JPG_FILES\\"+ lyr.name 
                                     +".jpg",resolution=300)
    lyr.visible = False
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ArcGIS 10.1 then the [**new RasterClassifiedSymbology class of arcpy.mapping**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000005p000000) may be what you need to look at.

Comment: Yeah, 10.0 does not have this option.

Comment: thank you for the advice. but it doesn't help. i don't have classidfied symbology. i have stretched symbology. when i check lyr.symbologyType it returns me "OTHER".

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy, sys, os, string 

arcpy.env.workspace = "PATH USER"

mxd_list = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")

for mxd in mxd_list:

    current_mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(ws, mxd))
    jpg_name = mxd[:-4] + ".jpg"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(current_mxd, jpg_name, resolution = NUMBERUSER)

del mxd_list
```

Comment: can you provide an explanation to your answer?